# Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?

Tags: узус

На наш миллионник, не более двух-трех пар.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая - нет. Если что и нужно, то тире, так как это неполное предложение, с нулевым сказуемым ***есть, приходится*** и т.п.

[Тире в неполном предложении.](https://www.yaklass.ru/materiali?chtid=661&mode=cht&subid=160)

> Тире в неполном предложении ставится, если пропущено сказуемое (чаще
>   всего) или какой-нибудь другой член предложения, но его можно легко
>   восстановить из контекста или из ситуации (Она пошла домой, он -
>   в кино)

Comment: И тут-таки в зависимости от контекста возможны варианты. "Интересно, сколько в нашем городе калош?" - "На наш миллионник - не более двух-трех пар." Или: "А много ли вам прислать калош?" - "На наш миллионник, не более двух-трех пар."